# Show data in Local Notification stored in plist file

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

How i can show data stored in plist file on local notifications??
how to create local notification in ios reads data from plist file?
I use below code to display data in alert view, but how I can change this data depending on time?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
  if (localNotif) {    
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hhh" message:@"Data for the first day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];    
  }
  return YES;

}
```

Thank you.